# Getting “Could not find part of the path” error

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload, directory

I am using the FileUploader control in my web application. I'd like to upload the file in a specified folder. As the specific folder does not exist yet, I have to create the path it in my codes.

```
Could not find part of the path.
mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path
'C:\Users\seldarine\Desktop\PROJ\ED_Project\SFiles\Submissions\blueteam\Source.zip
```

I believe there is a problem with my filePath. 
This is a portion of my codes:

```
 //teamName is a string passed from a session object upon login 
 string filePath = "SFiles/Submissions/" + teamName+ "/";

 //If directory does not exist
 if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
 { // if it doesn't exist, create

    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
 }

 f_sourceCode.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath + src));
 f_poster.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath + bb));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try :

```
//teamName is a string passed from a session object upon login 
 string filePath = "SFiles/Submissions/" + teamName+ "/";
 string severFilePath = Server.MapPath(filePath);
 // The check here is not necessary as pointed out by @Necronomicron in a comment below
 //if (!Directory.Exists(severFilePath))
 //{ // if it doesn't exist, create

    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(severFilePath);
 //}

 f_sourceCode.SaveAs(severFilePath + src));
 f_poster.SaveAs(severFilePath + bb));
```

You need to check and create directory based on `Server.MapPath(filePath);`, not `filePath` (I assume that your `src` and `bb` are filenames without any sub directory paths).

It's better to use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of concatenating strings:

```
f_sourceCode.SaveAs(Path.Combine(severFilePath,src));
f_poster.SaveAs(Path.Combine(severFilePath,bb));
```

Comment: I agree with using Path.Combine. It works well. Thanks.

Comment: No need to check if directory exists. `If the directory already exists, this method does not create a new directory, but it returns a DirectoryInfo object for the existing directory. `  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Necronomicron: Good catch, I did not notice that when copying the code.